# How to allow multiple users to access same level in laravel 7 Gate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6.2

i want to create a function which allows multiple users same Access level in the `AuthServiceProvider.php`
And i have tried using the && please provide me a solution for this issue,

Here's my `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;


class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // * Laravel ACL
        // ! Admin
        Gate::define('isAdmin', function ($user) {
            return $user->type === 'admin';
        });
        // ! Admin and author
        Gate::define('isAdminOrAuthor', function ($user) {
            return $user->type === 'admin' && 'author';
        });

        // ! Author
        Gate::define('isAuthor', function ($user) {
            return $user->type === 'author';
        });

        // ! User
        Gate::define('isUser', function ($user) {
            return $user->type === 'user';
        });


        Passport::routes();

        //
    }
}
```

And this is how i tried to give permission for Admin and Author

```
// ! Admin and author
    Gate::define('isAdminOrAuthor', function ($user) {
        return $user->type === 'admin' && 'author';
    });
```

This did not work, i just wanted to know how can i allow the same user levels to both users under the `isAdminOrAuthor` name.

Here's the place where i need to allow both admin and author to view

```
 @can('isAdmin')
    <li class="nav-item">
     <router-link to="users" class="nav-link ">
       <i class="fas fa-users nav-icon text-blue"></i>
           <p>Users</p>
           </router-link>
      </li>
 @endcan
```

i wanted to change the word `isAdmin` to `isAdminOrAuthor` so both the users can access it

Answer (score 0):

**Gate**

```
Gate::define('isAdminOrAuthor', function ($user) {
    return $user->type === 'admin' || $user->type === 'author';
});
```

**View**

```
@can('isAdminOrAuthor')
    <!-- Content visible to users with the 'isAdminOrAuthor' permission -->
@endcan
```